# Forcing axiom fails

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Consider the following forcing:

$P=Fn(\aleph_0,\aleph_0,\aleph_0)=${$p:$dom$(p)$ $ \to \aleph_0 |$ dom$(p)$ $ \subset \aleph_0,$ card(dom$(p)$) $<\aleph_0$}

Can someone give me a hint of how to prove that this way defined $P$ does not satisfy  "forcing axiom", i.e. the following does not hold:

For any set $\mathbb D$ of cardinality $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, there exists a filter $H$ on $P$ such that $H \cap D \neq \emptyset$ for every $D \in \mathbb D$ which is dense in $P$.

Comment: It's just the usual Cohen forcing, no? In this case, you should require that $\Bbb D$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, otherwise this is blatantly not provable. If CH holds, this is easily disprovable, and if MA holds then this is also false.

Comment: Yes it is. But shouldn't I then construct somehow $\mathbb D$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ to get a contradiction or?

Comment: But you wrote $\Bbb D$ has size strictly less than that... so?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I have just edited my post. @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote your forcing above (which is also Cohen forcing).

For each $x \in {}^\omega 2$, Let $D_x = \{p \in \mathbb{C} : (\exists n \in \mathrm{dom}(p))(p(n) \neq x(n))\}$. $D_x$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $E_n = \{p \in \mathbb{C} : n \in \mathrm{dom}(p)\}$. $E_n$ is dense.

Let $\mathcal{D} = \{D_x : x \in {}^\omega 2\} \cup \{E_n : n \in \omega\}$.

Note that any filter $F$ for $\mathbb{C}$ meeting all the $E_n$'s give a single real.

Now $\mathcal{D}$ has size $2^{\aleph_0}$. If your "forcing axiom" holds, then there is a $G$ in your universe $V$ which is a filter which meets all dense sets in $\mathcal{D}$. Let $g$ be the real which coming from $G$. Since $G \in V$, $g$ must be a real of $V$. But $G$ meets $D_g$ which implies $g \neq g$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P$ itself is countable. Take $\Bbb D$ to be the set of *all* dense open subsets.

Next, use the fact that $P$ is a nontrivial forcing, and therefore has no generic filters in the universe.